# Rails Active Record : How do you preload multi level association with an extra dynamic criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, preload

In the models :

```
  Organization has_many Users
    Users has_many Registrations
    Registration belongs_to Organization
```

In my view organization#show, I am going to have something like

```
organization.users.each do |user|
 user.registrations.where(organization_id: organization.id).each do |registration|
   # display a registration
 end
end
```

In the controller to avoid N + 1 query on registrations, I could do something like:

`@organization = Organization.includes(users: :registrations)find(params[:id])`

However this won't work because I actually have an extra criteria on registration `where(organization_id: organization.id)`.

How can I preload all registrations that belong to a user within the organization and that belong to the said organization to avoid N + 1 query here.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that a user belongs to an organization, there should be an `organization_id` in the `users` table, and the models must be related to each other. Perhaps you can try joining Registration with User and filtering by the `users.organization_id` column;

```
Registration.joins(:user).where(users: { organization_id: 1 })
```

Comment: Could you provide an example with some controller/view context because I dont really see how that makes me avoid the N+1 query here

Comment: It all ends up in what you really need. If you need only the registration data as I can see from your example "# display a registration" then selecting registrations from your database is all what it takes. You do have a N+1 problem right now because of the `organization.users[0].registration` you're doing.